Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Not Working for Date and String Match
I'm trying to apply conditional formatting in Google Sheets based on data from two sheets. In Sheet1, I have a list of dates (Column B) and apartment names (Columns C onwards). In Sheet2, I have apartment names, arrival dates, departure dates, and some extra info.
I used the following formula in the conditional formatting rule for the range C2:N1000 in Sheet1:
=AND($B2 >= VLOOKUP(C$1, Sheet2!$B$2:$F, 4, FALSE), $B2 <= VLOOKUP(C$1, Sheet2!$B$2:$F, 5, FALSE))
However, the conditional formatting is not working as expected. It should highlight the cell green if the date in Column B of Sheet1 falls between the arrival and departure dates for the corresponding apartment in Sheet2. This is the link to my google sheets if you need more info.
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?


Added one possible approach to your test sheet:
=countifs(indirect("Sheet2!B:B"),C$1,indirect("Sheet2!E:E"),"<="&$B2,indirect("Sheet2!F:F"),">="&$B2)



All of the dates in Column_B of Sheet1 are of year 2023 whilst in Sheet2 they are of 2024; for testing purposes changed Sheet1 dates to 2024

